# Xamarin, display pop-up with listviewItem

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a listview in my xamarin-app:

```
ListView x:Name="list"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Users" 
                     RowHeight="200"
                     ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

When I click on an Item, I have this method in the CB:

```
 public void OnItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            var user = e.Item as User;
            if (user == null)
            {
                //Display dialog with two buttons:
                //Edit user or delete user...
            }

        }
```

Im hoping to display a simple dialog-box with two buttons. The important thing is that I need to be able to pass the `User` to the "correct" method depending on the made choice. Help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of [pop-ups](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/) in Xamarin Forms - Alerts and Action Sheets.

If you only have two options, an Alert is probably the best choice:

```
var resp = await DisplayAlert (title, message, optionA, optionB);
```

`resp` is a `bool` that will tell you whether they clicked the first or second option.